# Show Azure Service Bus Topic Filters

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-topics

I am working my way through a great tutorial on using Azure PaaS and have come up with a question.
Here is the tutorial if it helps anybody else (been pretty useful for me)
https://youtu.be/ScJ4VxOmNGs

Is there a way outside of writing a C# program to check what filters are set on a Service Bus Topic Subscription Rule?

I can do this:

```
var rules = await processPaymentInventoryCheckedClient.GetRulesAsync();
```

And access them that way, but is there a way using CLI or Powershell?
I know that as of the date of this post you cannot do it in the portal.

I tried using Service Bus Explorer, and it shows the rule but not the filter:
[image: service bus filter missing]

SBE is awesome btw, very helpful if you have not used it:
https://github.com/paolosalvatori/ServiceBusExplorer

If I run the above C# code and then drill down into the properties I can verify that the filter is indeed applied:

[image]

Thank you --

Joe

Comment: If you're looking for an alternate tool to view the rules, may I suggest you take a look at Cerebrata Cerulean (https://www.cerebrata.com/products/cerulean). It has support for viewing and managing the same. https://i.stack.imgur.com/CgoM1.png [Full Disclosure: I am part of the team behind this tool].

Comment: Thanks Gaurav -- I will give the trail a try.  Tools to manage Azure are helpful.  I am still wanting to know if there is a way from a command line of some type.

Comment: Thanks! I did look briefly at the available Cmdlets and based on my limited search I was not able to find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding ServiceBus Explorer - it's a bug. The tool currently only shows `SqlFilter`s and not `CorrelationFilter`s. I've raised an [issue](https://github.com/paolosalvatori/ServiceBusExplorer/issues/199) to add support for `CorrelationFilter`s.

To list all filter you can use the following LinqPad script with a [free version of the tool](http://www.linqpad.net/download.aspx):

```
var connectionString = "<asb-connection-string>";
var topicPath = "<topic-path>";
var subName = "<subscription-name>";
var nsm = NamespaceManager.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString);

foreach (RuleDescription rule in await nsm.GetRulesAsync(topicPath,subName))
{
  if (rule.Filter is SqlFilter)
  {
    $"Rule: Name = {rule.Name} - 
        SqlExpression = {(rule.Filter as SqlFilter).SqlExpression}".Dump();
  }

  if (rule.Filter is CorrelationFilter)
  {
    $"Rule: Name = {rule.Name} - Correlate = {(rule.Filter as
        CorrelationFilter)}".Dump();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Sean...I was hoping for CLI but that will help.

Comment: I'm in the mids of fixing this issue with SBE. Stay tuned.

Comment: @JoeRuder the fix for SBE is pending and will be released in version 4.0.109. If you need it already, you can pull down [my PR](https://github.com/paolosalvatori/ServiceBusExplorer/pull/201), compile it and use. This is what it will look like: https://imgur.com/a/qz2aI